# Removing a list of items from a nested list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, nested-lists

Imagine a nested list as below.

```
["A","ABBA","ABABA"]
```

I would like to create a function which removes singleton elements from this list (in this example, "A"), *and* removes any lists containing that singleton element.

So that:

```
removeElems ["A","ABBA","CCC"] -> ["CCC"]
```

Below is my attempt at solving this problem:

```
badElements nested = concat $ filter (\c -> length c == 1) nested

removeElements nested = [c | c <- nested, u <- badElements nested, not $ any (==u) c]
```

This produces strange results where the multiple generators 'cycle' the nested list, such as below:

```
["A","ABBA","C","BCCB"] --> ["A","A","ABBA","ABBA","C","C","BCCB","BCCB"]--> ["A","ABBA","C","BCCB"]
```

Another example:

```
[[1],[1,2,3,4],[2],[5,6,7,8]] --> [5,6,7,8]
```

Comment: Define "strange results". Also, by De Morgan `not $ any (== u)` is better written as `all (/= u)`.

Comment: What do you define as a "bad element?"  Should "A" be removed because it appears in the outer list?  Could you please add some more examples of what you want the output to be like?

Comment: @delnan actually it's better written simply as `notElem u`, which is defined just like you wrote it, `notElem x = all (/= x)` [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-List.html#elem)

Comment: @Dan: Thanks, my stdlib-fu is weak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only want to produce zero or one outputs for each list element, you don't want a list comprehension that iterates over `badElements`.  Instead, you want to filter on a predicate that iterates over `badElements`.

What predicate?  Well, a list is good if it doesn't contain a bad element.  That is, all of its elements are not bad.

```
removeElements nested = filter (all (`notElem` badElements nested)) nested
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an untested attempt at it:

```
removeElements ls = filter (null . intersect singletons) ls
                    where singletons = mapMaybe singleElem ls
                          singleElem [x] = Just x
                          singleElem _ = Nothing
```

Comment: Or, without maybes, you could write `singletons = let s [x] = True; s _ = False in filter s` (where singletons is now a function `[[x]] -> [[x]]`)

Comment: In my code, `singletons` is a list, not a function (since it has the `ls` on the end of the `mapMaybe`).  I used `mapMaybe` to avoid needing to flatten the list of singletons, but I agree that `concat $ filter ... ls` works too.

Answer (score 1):

Another attempt:

```
badElements :: [[a]] -> [a]
badElements = concat . filter (\x -> 1 == length x)

removeBadElements :: (Eq a) => [[a]] -> [[a]]
removeBadElements xs = filter (\x -> not $ any ((flip elem) x) (badElements xs) ) xs
```

`badElements` will return a list with all the singleton elements of its parameter (similar to what your `badElements` is supposed to do:

```
badElements [[1],[1,2,3,4],[2],[5,6,7,8]]
[1,2]
```

`removeBadElements`, then, removes all the elements that contain an element of `badElements`.